# Easiest way to copy ASCII text into VirtualBox VM without Guest Additions?

Tags: virtualbox

### Specifically

On a Windows 7 machine running Oracle Virtualbox version 4.3 (the actual type of Virtualbox shouldn't matter, but just in case), what is the most painless way of copying plain text to the guest?

I don't want to install Guest Additions, because sometimes that's a nightmare, especially when the guest is a minimal install (i.e. lacks an X server, normal dev utilities like make, etc.), and besides it shouldn't require the abstraction of a "clipboard" on the guest because there's no associated type information; just streaming bytes as if someone were typing quickly on a normal keyboard.